# Changing font-size of slider title in bokeh

Tags: python, slider, bokeh

I am trying to increase the font-size of the title of a slider in bokeh (0.12.4). For any other object there seems to be a "something_font_size" attribute, but as far as I can tell this doesn't seem to be the case for a slider title as it's saved as a string. Is there a way of doing this using bokeh or do I need to find a way to fix it using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not certain if you can fix this using bokeh. 
Try see what attributes and methods can be applied to the slider object.

If that fails, you could change it through investigating the elements on chrome/firefox then adding these to a styles.css file or similar.

```
 .bk-slider-parent
 {
  font-size:20px
 }
```

That seemed to increase both the name and value font sizes, you can also change just the values font size/color etc...

Let me just add that I am running with
bokeh serve --show Appdirectory

and Appdirectory contains main.py, Templates/index.html ,  Templates/styles.css - so you can include the snippet in either file (styles.css is included in index.html)

**Updated:** See below for bare minimum index.html should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        {{ bokeh_css }}
        {{ bokeh_js }}
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            {{ plot_div|indent(8) }}
            {{ plot_script|indent(8) }}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I managed to get the desired behaviour by using `.bk-slider-parent{ font-size:20px;} input[type="text"] { font-size:20px !important; width:3em !important;}` But I haven't managed to find an explanation of how to embed the main.py file in the index.html file. Would you be able to tell me what the line I'm missing is please?

Comment: create a folder called myapp  then place main.py in myapp/main.py and myapp/templates/index.html.  To run, type bokeh serve --show myapp.

Comment: But what should index.html look like? Presumably I need a line to call main.py?

Comment: If you are running with bokeh serve --show myappdirectory, you dont need to. Also html documents cant directly call python scripts, that is where bokeh comes in by generating the javascript scripts and embedding them.  See my post I updated it to include an example of index.html

Comment: Great! If you could accept my answer too that would be awesome. Also read http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html for more detailed explanations.